# Change value of <input> with two different <select> fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the number of `0` that are being selected from the `<select>` fields and want to display the addition result into the `<input>` field. Also, the value of the `<input>` field must change in real time if the user decides to change it to some other value that is not `0`.

Now the issue is, I want to display `2` if both the `<select>` field values are `0` and should display `1` if only one of them has `0` value. But, if I am changing the value of either of the `<select>` fields two times, the values are changing to `0`. I hope I am making sense.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  
  $('#s1').change(function() {
    var f1 = $(this).val();
    
    if (f1 == 0 && f1 != '') {
      ++count;
    } else {
      if (count > 0) {
        --count;
      }
    }
    
    $('#total').val(count);
  });
  
  $('#s2').change(function() {
    var f1 = $(this).val();
    
    if (f1 == 0 && f1 != '') {
      ++count;
    } else {
      if (count > 0) {
        --count;
      }
    }
    
    $('#total').val(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="s1">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="total" value="0">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some closing brackets. Your if statements aren't correctly closed before beginning the else statements. Your document ready function doesn't appear to be closed properly either.

Comment: please ignore the brackets as they might have been misplaced while reformatting the code here. please be rest assured that the brackets are there in my original code. haha

Comment: I have edited the question and added the necessary brackets, thanks for highlighting thought, much appreciated.

Comment: you should just have a single handler that checks the value of both when either change and updates the result.

Comment: how am I supposed to achieve this? Im not sure I follow, apologies.

Comment: In both cases, your else does nothing. Is it supposed to be doing something?

Comment: yes, the else block is supposed to --count variable. I have edited the code, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Once the missing brackets are added back, I'm not seeing a problem. It works for me on codepen. Are you expecting some other behavior? https://codepen.io/joshschroder/pen/ExeOWgM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one function that runs when either input changes.  It should check both of the field values and do the appropriate thing.

The logic was initially simple and for 2 elements, but for more than two you do need to count the number of zeroes in the selects.  The code for that turns out to be way shorter too, hah.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.countme').change(function() {
    // count all the selects with zero value
    const count = [...document.querySelectorAll(".countme")]
      .reduce((acc, el) => acc + (el.value === "0" ? 1 : 0), 0)
    $('#total').val(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="countme">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="countme">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="countme">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="total" value="0">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works like a charm! However, what if I have 5 different <select> fields? And what if I have 10? Will this same logic work? As I am not sure about the `else` part where the value is being set to `1` manually. Please advise.

Comment: Take a look now, yes you do need to count for more than 2 elements.

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to apply this logic to a form I am currently working with. The link to the form is this - https://rdclinicalskills.com/app/ I want the form to display the number of `0` selected into the "Items Missed" field as well as the "Overall Total Items Missed" field at the bottom. Also, the "Overall Total Points Possible" defaults to `82` and I want its value to change by `2` every time a user selects `NA` from the dropdown.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry but I'm not going to dig through your website.  If you want you can update your question with the relevant differences.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @James's answer, a more "*jquery-esq*" way would be to use `.filter()`:

```
let count = $(".countme").filter((_, e) => e.value === "0").length;
```

A single handler for every `select` that recalculates the total every time rather than trying to keep track of a "running total" with + and - values; these frequently go wrong somewhere and you're left with your total out-of-sync - so just recalculate each time.

Updated snippet:

```js
$('.countme').change(function() {
  let count = $(".countme").filter((i, e) => e.value==="0").length;
  $('#total').val(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="countme">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="countme">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="countme">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="total" value="0">
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Please don't forget to upvote any/all answers that were useful and pick the one you used as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, please see my comment to James' reply.

Comment: Your site is blocked for me.   Accept one of these answers, and ask a new question, including the *relevant* code in a snippet.  You should be able to reduce the code to just the relevant parts (see [mcve]).  If not, you can also post an *additional* link to a jsfiddle.net with more code (ie include the relevant code in the question, link to this question and include more code in a fiddle)